# Unix touch command usage

Tags: unix, touch

I know you can use touch to create a new empty file.

I just learned that touch can be used to update the access and modification time of a file. I don't quite know in what situations and why do you need to update the access and modification time of a file , i.e. the usefulness of this particular function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some utility depends on timestamp of the file.

For example, `make` uses timestamp to check whether it is required to do something (usually build) based on the timestamp of the source code, and output (executable, object files, ...)

By `touch`ing followed by `make`, the source file, you can force rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, `touch` has a `-d` option that can fake the modification time.
If one "knows what he's doing" she can avoid long build time, due to unnecessary re-compilations.

For example, when adding a declaration to a common header file,
that does not change any old API, one can fake the header real modification time,
and bypass Makefile's dependencies.